# How can I extract specific text from string using REGEXP_EXTRACT (BigQuery)?

Tags: regex, google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table with strings.
Each string contains parameters with two types delimiters like `;` and `_`.
For example `"&G2-1 O; 3_45; GFAV; wy; iiiiiiiu; euuw..."`

I need to extract first three parameters: `offer-code`(ex. `"&G2-1 O"`), `id`(ex. `3`) and sub_id (ex. `45`). Parameter order will be same from the beginning of strings.

```
WITH t0 as (
SELECT 'ASD-1 UU; 3_4; GFAV; wyeuuw...' AS full_code
UNION ALL
SELECT '#YA2-1 SA; 23_4; AFF; lKjsdj ;uuw...'
UNION ALL
SELECT '&G2-1 O; 3_45; GFAV; wy; iiiiiiiu; euuw...')

SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(full_code, '[^;]*') as code,
   REGEXP_EXTRACT(full_code, '(/d*)_(/d*)') as id 
FROM t0
```

With this query I can get `code` parameter. How can I get another ones: `id` and `sub_id`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a different approach first split the string by ; to elements. Then use each element further.

```
WITH t0 as (
SELECT 'ASD-1 UU; 3_4; GFAV; wyeuuw...' AS full_code
UNION ALL
SELECT '#YA2-1 SA; 23_4; AFF; lKjsdj ;uuw...'
UNION ALL
SELECT '&G2-1 O; 3_45; GFAV; wy; iiiiiiiu; euuw...')
, elements as (SELECT 
  split(full_code,';') as e
FROM t0)
select e,e[offset(0)] as code,
  trim(split(e[offset(1)],'_')[offset(0)]) as id,
  trim(split(e[offset(1)],'_')[offset(1)]) as sub_id 
from elements
```

this returns:

```
{"e": [
  "ASD-1 UU",
  " 3_4",
  " GFAV",
  " wyeuuw..."
],
"code": "ASD-1 UU",
"id": "3",
"sub_id": "4"
},
```